# I don't get a print result of function when using range

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, range, collatz

Why can't I see the result of the function when I use `range()`? I want to create a range of numbers where each the number will be evaluate in "colla" function. But range doesn't work with "colla"

```py
def colla(num):
    fin = []
    while num != 1:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num = num // 2
            fin.append(0)
        elif num % 2 == 1:
            num = 3 * num + 1
            fin.append(1)
    counter = []
    for Z in fin:
        if Z == 0:
            counter.append(Z)
    return ("{:.0%}".format((len(counter)/len(fin))))

for i in range(5):   
    print(colla(i)) # here I have a problem!
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: There's no error message. The program loops for a long time.

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code. It quickly becomes obvious that you're stuck in an infinite loop (because `range()` starts at `0` and `num % 2 == 0` and `num // 2` is also `0`) [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: no error message, when i run program all is empty

Comment: colla works without range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `colla()` function requires input numbers of 2 and above.

Try this:

```py
for i in range(2,6):   
    print(colla(i))
```

Please be aware that calling `colla(0)` will result in an infinite loop, or rather "out of memory" when `fin` fills up with `0`s. Also calling `colla(1)` results in a `ZeroDivisionError` because `fin` will be an empty list.

Comment: Yeah! It works. Thank you! I realized,  my range starting with  zero number and creating infity loop